# problemas con el insert into

Tags: php

a primeros de este mes pedi ayuda para el insert into y en su momento lo que me ofrecieron fnciono, ahora vuelvo a pedir ayuda pues se me encripto el programa y aunque he vuelto a probar la solucion que se me dio en su dia, ahora no me funciona. Esto de ser novato en la materia trae sus consecuencias. Si no os molesta podeis ayudarme de nuevo? Os paso de nuevo el codigo. Gracias

```
    <?php
    
   //Seleccionar la base de datos
$db=mysqli_select_db($link,"javiers1_proyecto");

//crear las variables para los campos de textos

                 $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
                 $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
                 $email=$_POST['email'];
                 $direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
                 $poblacion=$_POST['poblacion'];
                 $provincia=$_POST['provincia'];
                 $cp=$_POST['cp'];
                 $movil=$_POST['movil'];
                 $adultos=$_POST['adultos'];
                 $infantiles=$_POST['infantiles'];
                 $fechareserva=$_POST['fechareserva'];
                 $horareserva=$_POST['horareserva'];
                 $alergias=$_POST['alergias']; 



//crear una consulta

$sql="INSERT INTO reservas (id,nombre, apellidos, email, direccion, poblacion, provincia, cp, movil, adultos, infantiles, fechareserva, horareserva, alergias, freg) VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, NOW())";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, 'ssssssiiiiiiss',$nombre, $apellidos, $email, $direccion, $poblacion, $provincia, $cp, $movil, $adultos, $infantiles, $fechareserva, $horareserva, $alergias); 

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_execute($link,$resultado);

if($stmt == false){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
}else{
    echo '<script> alert("Reserva registrada");
          location.href="index.php";                    
          </script>';

    mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
}

//ejecutar la consulta
$my_error=mysqli_error($link);

//verificar
        if(!empty($my_error)) {

        echo "Ha habido un error al insertar los valores. $my_error";

    } else{

       echo "Los datos han sido introducidos satisfactoriamente";

    }

    
?>
```

Gracias de ante mano.

P.D.: El archivo trata de hacer reservas on line.

Comment: Al parecer te falta una "s" a lo ultimo en tu : ($resultado, 'ssssssiiiiiisi',$nom, $ape) y procura colocar el ";" al final de tu sentencia INSERT.

Comment: ya  funciona, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: que bueno, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar cambiar las siguientes lineas, a ver que cambios se pueden presentar:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO reservas (id,nombre, apellidos, email, direccion, poblacion, provincia, cp, movil, adultos, infantiles, fechareserva, horareserva, alergias, freg) VALUES (null,'".$nombre."','".$apellidos."','".$email."', '".$direccion."','".$poblacion."','".$provincia."','".$cp."', '".$movil."','".$adultos."','".$infantiles."','".$fechareserva."', '".$horareserva."', '".$alergias."', NOW())";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```